# Get Element by tag inside GetElementsbyClass inside GetElementbyID nested dom elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have html output like this:

```
<div id="parent">
  <ul id="list">
    <li class="item">
      <a href="picture1.jpg">
        <img src="picture1.jpg">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="item active">
      <a href="picture1.jpg" class="OUR-TARGET">
        <img src="picture1.jpg">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <a href="picture1.jpg">
        <img src="picture1.jpg">
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I would like to get all of the elements with tag 'a' that are within an element with classname 'active' and also within the id 'parent'.

I am currently using
`document.getElementById('parent').getElementsByTagName('a')` but I don't want all of the inactive a tags, just the ones that are active by way of the nested elements with class=active.  Thanks!

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("#parent .active a")`

Comment: `$("#parent .active a")` since OP have tagged jQuery

Comment: That did the trick...I couldn't figure this out for the life of me.  How do I mark your answer as the "answer?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Long way

At first, get elements only with `active` class, and then, iterate through this elements and get child `a` elements. Here is an example (I gave `OUR-TARGET` class to our target, so you can see it in console finally and be sure, that it's really our target):

```js
var activeLis = document.getElementById('parent').getElementsByClassName('active');
for (var i = 0; i < activeLis.length; i++) {
  console.log(activeLis[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0]);
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <ul id="list">
    <li class="item">
      <a href="picture1.jpg">
        <img src="picture1.jpg">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="item active">
      <a href="picture1.jpg" class="OUR-TARGET">
        <img src="picture1.jpg">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <a href="picture1.jpg">
        <img src="picture1.jpg">
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

### Short way

You can simply use `"#parent .active a"` selector for `querySelectorAll` method:

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll("#parent .active a")[0]);
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <ul id="list">
    <li class="item">
      <a href="picture1.jpg">
        <img src="picture1.jpg">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="item active">
      <a href="picture1.jpg" class="OUR-TARGET">
        <img src="picture1.jpg">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <a href="picture1.jpg">
        <img src="picture1.jpg">
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I was actually hoping to get all items that were active, not just the first one (assume there are multiple). I think that can be accomplished by removing the [0]?  That's what worked for me.

Comment: @dstep, yes, I logged `[0]` element just for example.